# My laptop cannot adjust brightness

Tags: fedora, hardware, gnome3, compiz

I have a problem adjusting my laptop's brightness. This is a hardware problem but I can solve it  with `ccsm`, but other programs do not work for me, e.g., `xgamma`, etc.

Now I am running Fedora 15 and Gnome3 I cannot use compiz: is there another solution?

Comment: I think this problem is about Gnome 3, not Fedora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found a way to solve this problem on Acer with Fedora 15 (thanks to Fedora forums and answers here):

1. Update the BIOS to the lastest version.
2. Edit `/etc/Xorg/xorg.conf` to add the following line under `Section "Device"`:

   ```
   Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
   ```
3. Edit `/boot/grub/grub.conf` to add the parameters `acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux` on the kernel command line (at the end of the line that looks like `linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1 ro`).
4. Reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Try editing `/etc/default/grub` to set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` to `acpi_osi=Linux` and then running `update-grub`. I found it in [this Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10112062&postcount=6); it worked on my Acer Aspire, but I'm not sure if it works on other computers

Comment: how can i config grub in fedora dont hav /etc/default/grub

Comment: This solution worked on my HP Envy 17 2001g while running Crunchbang Statler with Kernel 3.2... just saying, if anyone comes across here :D

Answer (score 2):

I was with the same problem in my laptop, a Dell Vostro 3300 with Ubuntu 11.04, [this configuration solved my problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39391/adjusting-brightness-on-dell-vostro-3500-wont-work/43683#43683).

- Edit `/etc/Xorg/xorg.conf` to add the following line under `Section "Device"`:

  ```
  Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
  ```
- Edit `/etc/default/grub and add`acpi_osi=Linux`to the`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` setting, i.e.

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
  ```

  then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: Please do more than just link to an answer. At the very least summarize the answer or copy the most important parts of the config you reference into your answer.

Comment: edit /etc/default/grub to change the line into:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"`
/etc/default/grub in fedora not found. How can i config grub?

Answer (score 1):

I only had to add

```
Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
```

to /etc/Xorg/xorg.conf. When adding the parameters (which are mentioned in other posts) to /etc/default/grub, the brightness adjustment did still work but displaying the brightness level when changing the brightness did not change any more.

Im running Ubuntu 11.10 and Gnome3, on a Lenovo T420s