# Missing /etc/default/grub in fedora15

Tags: fedora, grub2

Based on [this suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16824/my-laptop-cannot-adjust-brightness/16825#16825), I want to edit `/etc/default/grub` to add the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

However, I don't have that file on my system. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have the grub package installed? Did you remove the file earlier?

Comment: i just known f15 not use grub2 and it cant config to /etc/default/grub

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well `/etc/default` is a Debian/Ubuntu thing, so you're unlikely to find it in Fedora.

You don't need it though - just add the option to the command line for the current entries in `grub.conf` and Fedora will preserve it when installing new kernels.

Comment: An [anonymous user](http://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9845) suggests that since Fedora 18, there is now a file `/etc/default/grub`, similar to the one in Debian/Ubuntu. (Dear anonymous user: this should have been submitted as an answer, not by editing an existing answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to change /boot/grub/grub.conf?

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 15 uses grub2. You should have /etc/grub.conf symlinked to /boot/grub/menu.lst

Comment: No it doesn't. Fedora 16 will likely use grub2, but Fedora 15 still uses grub 0.97.

Comment: grub 0.97 is a prerelease version of grub2